# C3 char inside flexbox

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, c3.js

I want to have a c3 chart that fulfill a web page. I am trying to use Flexbox.

I use Flex-direction column and add a header and a div. The div as the only grow element. It seems to work well while I resize to upper sizes but its broken when I shrink the windows

See example at: https://codepen.io/josubg/full/RQNJyN/

```js
function showChart(config){
    return c3.generate(config);
}
 

function  fixSize() {
        var a =document.getElementById("widget-container");
        cs.resize({"height": a.clientHeight, "width":a.clientWidth})
    }


var labels = ['Month 0', 'Month 18', 'Month 24', 'Month 30', 'Month 36'];
var values = ['Index', 4, 4, null, null, null];

// Include a mark for denote that are axis labels
labels.unshift('x');

var config = {
  bindto: d3.select("#chart_a"),
  onresized: fixSize,
  line: {
    connectNull: true
  },
  legend: {
    show: false
  },
  data: {
    x : "x",
    columns: [
      labels,
      values
    ],
    type: "bar"
  },
  grid: {
    show: true,
    y: {
      lines: [
        {value: 8, text: 'Goal', class: 'goal'},
        {value: 4, text: 'Baseline', class:'baseline'}
      ]
    }
  },
  axis: {
    x: {
      type: 'category'
    },
    y:{
      show:false,
      max: 9
    }
  }
};
cs = showChart(config);
cs.flush();
```

```css
body{

    height: 100vh ;
    width: 100vw ;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#widget-container{
    background-color: fuchsia;
    flex-grow: 1;
}


div.c3{
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.18/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

  <h1>A chart!</h1>
  <div id="widget-container">
    <div id="chart_a"></div> 
  </div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.18/c3.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

The awful backgrounds are to ease view the elements size.

Comment: We can't reproduce your project, can't you share an image? or a codepen? jsfiddle?

Comment: I added the snippet and a code pen

Comment: It seens to be a problem with the plugin c3, take a look at these pages https://codepen.io/michaellee/pen/eNodMx http://c3js.org/samples/api_resize.html